# How can I make my "two legged" modular robot to move in Gazebo (it seems "pinned" by a fixed joint and unmovable)?

Tags: ros2, gazebo-simu, moveit

I am currently working on a "two legs" modular robot (cuboctaedric units with some revolute joints) and I have to make it move in Gazebo.
Problem is, when I move the joints of my robot and it doesn't touch the ground anymore, it doesn't fall in Gazebo, the cylindrical link is pinned and so is the entire robot :
[The robot doesn't touch the ground but doesn't fall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML6DU.png)

Here is what the robot looks like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4CY1.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZx2I.png)

I built this model starting with the cylindrical link at the top (the one between the two "legs"), and there is a fixed joint between this link and a virtual link named world. Here is the URDF file I created for this robot :

```
<link name="world"/>


<!-- virtual joint -->
<joint name="virtual_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="link1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.99"/>
</joint>


<link name="link1">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 ${pi/2.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.04" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>
    
    <collision>
        <origin rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 ${pi/2.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.04" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="0.5" r="0.1" h="0.04" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 ${pi/2.0}" />
</link>


<!-- left arm -->
<joint name="top_left" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link1" />
    <child link="link2" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.02 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link2">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="-0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="-0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="-0.14 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- test représentation cuboctaèdre par cube pour inertia -->
<!-- <link name="link2">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.28 0.28 0.28" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link> -->


<joint name="joint2_3" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link2" />
    <child link="link3" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.14 0 -0.28" />
</joint>


<link name="link3">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint3_4" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link3" />
    <child link="link4" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.15"/>
</joint>


<link name="link4">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="-${pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="-${pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="1.0" r="0.1" h="0.18" xyz="0 0 -0.08" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- test représentation joint1_z par cylindre pour inertia -->
<!-- <link name="link4">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.08" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.18" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link> -->


<joint name="middle_left" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link4" />
    <child link="link5" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.13" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link5">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.065" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.065" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:sphere_inertia m="0.5" r="0.065" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint5_6" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link5" />
    <child link="link6" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.13"/>
</joint>


<link name="link6">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${pi/2}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${pi/2}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="1.0" r="0.1" h="0.18" xyz="0 0 0.07" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- test représentation joint1_z par cylindre pour inertia -->
<!-- <link name="link6">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.07" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.18" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link> -->


<joint name="bottom_left" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link6" />
    <child link="link7" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.15" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link7">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0 0 -0.01" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- right arm -->
<joint name="top_right" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link1" />
    <child link="link8" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.02 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link8">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0.14 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint8_9" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link8" />
    <child link="link9" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.14 0 -0.28" />
</joint>


<link name="link9">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint9_10" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link9" />
    <child link="link10" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.15"/>
</joint>


<link name="link10">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="-${pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="-${pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="1.0" r="0.1" h="0.18" xyz="0 0 -0.08" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="middle_right" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link10" />
    <child link="link11" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.13" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link11">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.065" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.065" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:sphere_inertia m="0.5" r="0.065" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint11_12" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link11" />
    <child link="link12" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.13"/>
</joint>


<link name="link12">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${pi/2}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${pi/2}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="1.0" r="0.1" h="0.18" xyz="0 0 0.07" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="bottom_right" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link12" />
    <child link="link13" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.15" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link13">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0 0 -0.01" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- Transmissions-->
<xacro:default_transmission name="top_left"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="middle_left"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="bottom_left"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="top_right"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="middle_right"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="bottom_right"/>
```

I also defined controllers for the joints with the JointTrajectoryController for Gazebo and MoveIt. Here is my controllers.yaml :

controller_manager:
ros__parameters:
update_rate: 10

```
left_arm_controller:
  type : joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

right_arm_controller:
  type : joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

joint_state_broadcaster:
  type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
```

left_arm_controller:
ros__parameters:
joints:
- top_left
- middle_left
- bottom_left

```
command_interfaces:
  - position

state_interfaces:
  - position

open_loop_control: true
allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true
```

right_arm_controller:
ros__parameters:
joints:
- top_right
- middle_right
- bottom_right

```
command_interfaces:
  - position

state_interfaces:
  - position

open_loop_control: true
allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true
```

And here is the moveit_controllers.yaml :

```
moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager

moveit_simple_controller_manager:  

controller_names:
- left_arm_controller
- right_arm_controller  

left_arm_controller:
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
type: FollowJointTrajectory
default: true
joints:
  - top_left
  - middle_left
  - bottom_left  

right_arm_controller:
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
type: FollowJointTrajectory
default: true
joints:
  - top_right
  - middle_right
  - bottom_right
```

Ideally I would like to make the robot move like this :
[Automatde movement](https://amiraa.pages.cba.mit.edu/self-replicating-hierarchical-modular-robotic-swarms/recursive_swarm/demos/indexRecursion.html)
[Manual movement](https://amiraa.pages.cba.mit.edu/self-replicating-hierarchical-modular-robotic-swarms/recursive_swarm/demos/indexIK_parts.html)

Is ther a way to achieve this in ROS2 ?